# Why can't we talk about the potential energy of a single particle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy

Suppose there are two bodies (call them A and B) exerting gravitational forces on each other. The way I understand how potential energy works is: since the two bodies exert conservative forces on each other, whatever kinetic energy is lost by A as it travels through a path $c$ due to B doing negative work on A can be completely recovered by traversing the path $c$ in the opposite direction. This "recoverable" work is what's known as potential energy. My question is, why can't talk about the potential energy of a single body? Why must we only talk about the potential energy of a system containing *both* bodies? Say we included only body A in our system. The fact that A feels a conservative force (an external force) from B doesn't change, and hence A is subjected to the same "recoverable work" as before and hence has potential energy. In that sense, isn't it perfectly fine to talk about the potential energy of a system containing only containing a single body?

Comment: As energy is a relative measure, talking about the energy of a single body is meaningless. If you only have body A in the system, why talk about a force from B?

Comment: Potential energy describes interaction between bodies.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [What is meant by 'Gravitational Potential Energy of a System'?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651064/what-is-meant-by-gravitational-potential-energy-of-a-system)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is define a system.

Suppose the system consists of one body.
Having defined the system then one can identify **external** forces, forces which originate from outside the system.
Those external forces can change the motion of the body ie its velocity and kinetic energy as per the work-energy theorem.
For example, a mass (system) falling towards the Earth (providing the external force on the system).
Applying Newton's second law, $\text {force = mass}\times \rm acceleration \Rightarrow m\,g = m\, a \Rightarrow a=g$.
In terms of $\text{work done = change in kinetic energy}\Rightarrow m\,g\,\Delta h = \Delta \left(\frac 12 m v^2\right)$.

Notice that there is no motion of gravitational potential energy although this looks very much like an relationship that you are familiar with, $\text{loss in gravitational potential energy = gain in kinetic energy}$.

Now consider a system of two or more bodies.
There can now be external forces and **internal** forces acting on the system of bodies.
The external forces originate from outside the system and the internal forces are always Newton third law pairs of forces, equal in magnitude, opposite in direction and acting on different bodies.

Now go back to the Earth and falling mass and treat the Earth and the falling mass as one system with no external forces acting on the system.
The two internal forces are the force of gravitational attraction on the falling mass due to the Earth and the force of gravitational attraction on the Earth due to the falling mass.
One could go back and define two systems each containing a single body but it is often more convenient to introduce another form of energy to deal with such a situation which in this case called gravitational potential energy.

One reason for defining such a quantity is that energy is a scalar unlike a force which is a vector and in many situations it is easier to deal with energy (simple addition) rather than forces (vector addition).
So in terms of energies one can write $\text{loss in gravitational potential energy = gain in kinetic energy} \Rightarrow mg\Delta h = \dfrac 12 mv_{\rm final}^2 - \dfrac 12 m v_{\rm initial}^2$ and comparing this is with one of the kinematic equations for constant acceleration $2\,a\,\Delta h=v_{\rm final}^2 - v_{\rm initial}^2$ gives $a=g$ as before.

I hope that I have shown you why you cannot define a potential energy for a single body and the started you on the route to understanding why the introduction of potential energy enable you to solve problems in terms of energy rather than forces which often can be the easier route to the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

The law of [conservation of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy) , as all laws, is based  on experimental [observations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy#History). Potential energy as a concept is necessary in order to fulfill the law in all system with interactions between bodies.

A single non interacting  body has no kinetic energy at rest, and just kinetic energy if in a moving frame.

> The fact that A feels a conservative force (an external force) from B doesn't change

By your definition of the state above,  "feels" means "interaction", which means "not an isolated body".

> In that sense, isn't it perfectly fine to talk about the potential energy of a system containing only containing a single body?

No , this is wrong. Potential energy needs an interacting system. If the system has only one non interacting body there is no possible definition of potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

In many situations, you can consider the force exerted by the second body as an external force (e.g. a small mass in the gravitational field of the earth; a charge in a large scale electric field in the lab). In these cases it is perfectly common to consider only the potential energy of the first body with regard to some reference position (so strictly speaking it is only a potential energy difference).